# Article before preposition

Tags: preposition, article

Article before preposition

I can not understand why before preposition there is article, preposition has not gender so how to choose it ? example: "der innerhalb" in these sentences:

> Nach der neuen Regel soll Patienten innerhalb einer Woche ein Behandlungstermin in zumutbarer Entfernung vermittelt werden, **der innerhalb** der nächsten vier Wochen stattfindet.
>
> **Der innerhalb** der Universität an der Wende vom 17. zum 18. Jahrhundert einsetzende Sprachenwechsel, die Ablösung des Gelehrtenlateins durch die Volkssprache, stellt kein isoliertes, auf rein Sprachliches zu reduzierendes Phänomen dar, [...].

maybe these DER are pronouns?

Comment: I'd say no, but I'm not 100% sure. But note that the articles der, die and das can also be used as pronouns. [Source (german site)](http://gymbasis.ch/moodle/Deutsch/Grammatik/WortartenPronomen/index.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first sentence "der" is not an article, it's a relative pronoun and means "which".

Another example:

> Ein kleines Haus, das zwischen den Bäumen gebaut wurde - a small house which was built between the trees.

In the second sentence "der" is an article indeed but it relates to "Sprachenwechsel", not to "innerhalb". The whole part "*innerhalb der Universität an der Wende vom 17. zum 18. Jahrhundert einsetzende*" is an attributive phrase. You can think of it as of an adjective:

> Der Sprachenwechsel-> (der *neue* Sprachenwechsel) -> der *innerhalb der Universität an der Wende vom 17. zum 18. Jahrhundert einsetzende* Sprachenwechsel

BTW where does the second sentence come from? It's not complete and ends in the middle.

Comment: thanks very much, the sentence I found by a Google search